# Embedding conditions within a string

Tags: python, string

This is what I want to do 
An example

```
Dogwood = TRUE
Wetdog = 'wet dog'
drydog = 'dog'
s = 'I see a ', Wetdog if dog wet else drydog
print(s)
# which does not work...is there a way to make it work?

#However this works
print('I see a ', Wetdog if dogwet else drydog)
```

I want the same thing to work but in a variable string which can be printed when needed.

Comment: where is `dog wet` coming from or  `dogwet` ? What is `Dogwood = TRUE`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to assign the contents of the conditional to a string, you can use the format shown below. More explanation on this can be found here [Conditional Expression](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html)

I do not see `dog` or `wet` in your code above. Assuming that they exist, and that they are something like this...

```
dog = False #initial state of the dog
wet = True #state of a wet dog
```

Then the code below will work just fine

```
s = 'I see a {}'.format(Wetdog) if dog == wet else 'I see a {}'.format(drydog)
```

Comment: I think that sometimes code only can be ok because if its just a format error, the code is self explanatory... never-the-less, I have updated my answer

Comment: You also have variables that don't exist but then again so does the OP

Comment: @PadraicCunningham They are in the original question's source listing

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation (the `+` operator):

```
s = 'I see a ' + (Wetdog if dogwet else drydog)
```

Comment: Who's "we", kemosabe?  Personally, I encourage people to use string concatenation when they want to concatenate strings -- why do you think it's in Python **for**?

Comment: I would be more concerned about the fact `dogwet` does not appear to exist anywhere in the code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, sure, the OP's accidentally misnamed that variable as the mysterious `Dogwood` and then also mistyped it once as `dog wet` which would cause a `SyntaxError` due to the stray whitespace.  Both issues are pretty obvious and just as obviously not connected to "embedding conditions within a string".

Comment: I don't think anything is obvious in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is to do something like this:

```
Wetdog = 'wet dog'
drydog = 'dog'

dogiswet = True;  #can be True or False depending on what you want it to be
dogisdry = True;  #can be True or False depending on what you want it to be

if dogiswet:
  print "I see a %s." % Wetdog

if dogisdry:
  print "I see a %s." % drydog
```